# Python libraries to generate charts and save as image file

Tags: python, charts, python-2.7, bar-chart, pygooglechart

I require to generate bar charts and then save them as images, in .png or .bmp format.
Can anyone please point me to such libraries.

My basic need is to generate bar charts in an excel report.

I thought of generating bar charts from any chart library as image files and then insert them into the excel report i am generating using xlwt library.

Please let me know if there is a better way to achieve this objective.

** I had read about pygooglechart module, but i think we need internet connection to generate charts and then download them. Please correct me if i am wrong about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: I did look at matplotlib, but to me it seemed too complex for simplest of charts. I requirments of bar chart are very basic.

Comment: The example [barchart](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) looks pretty simple.

Comment: +1 matplotlib should work well, and is better to know than the most obscure/unmaintained packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can save to file with pygooglechart

```
chart = PieChart2D(700, 400)
chart.add_data([10, 10, 30, 200])
chart.set_pie_labels([
    'Budding Chemists',
    'Propane issues',
    'Meth Labs',
    'Attempts to escape morgage',
])
chart.download('chart.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple chart can be built in this way:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Link for this example:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py

Link for other examples:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html